# What needs to be redone to make the code read the entered information

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

how the "def" function should be redone
to read the urls entered by the user from the interface, and check for availability with output

I tried to do it, but it didn't work, I don't understand how to do it right

```
import requests
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from sys import argv


def SiteChek():
    sylk = weight_tf.get()
    for url in sylk:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            messagebox.showinfo(f"{url = }")

            messagebox.showinfo(f"{response.status_code = }")
            time.sleep(0.4)

window = Tk()
window.title("SiteChecker")
window.geometry('400x300')
frame = Frame(
    window,
    padx = 10,
    pady = 10
)
frame.pack(expand=True)
weight_lb = Label(
    frame,
    text="Insert links "
)
weight_lb.grid(row=3, column=1)
weight_tf = Entry(
    frame,
)
weight_tf.grid(row=3, column=3)
cal_btn = Button(
    frame,
    command = SiteChek,
    text='Start checking',
)
cal_btn.grid(row=4, column=3)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is how to do it :

```
def SiteCheck():
    Site_Value=GetSiteBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    Get_Response = requests.get(Site_Value)
    if Get_Response != 200:
        messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Will It Works ?', message = f"The website \"{Site_Value}\" works ! ")
    else : 
        messagebox.showerror(title="OH NO !", message= f"The website \"{Site_Value}\" doesn't works ")
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

`GetSiteBox.get("1.0","end-1c")` retrieves all the text entered into the `GetSiteBox` widget, from the beginning of the text to the end of the text, minus the last newline character. It uses the `get()` method of the `Text` widget, which takes two arguments for the starting and ending index of the text to retrieve.
As well as the `messagebox` that i modified because u needed to write `title=` and for the message part `message=`.

As for this part :

```
MainFrame = Frame(
    window,
    padx = 10,
    pady = 10
)
MainFrame.pack(expand=True)
weight_lb = Label(
    MainFrame,
    text="Insert links "
)
weight_lb.grid(row=3, column=1)
GetSiteBox = Text(
    MainFrame,
    height=1,
    width= 20
)
GetSiteBox.grid(row=3, column=3)
Check_Button = Button(
    MainFrame,
    command = SiteCheck,
    text='Start checking',
)
Check_Button.grid(row=4, column=3)





window.mainloop()
```

I just made `GetSiteBox` a `Text` Widget to make it easier and made some GUI modificiation because of the `Text` Widget and I also changed the names of the variables so it will be more easy for you if you want to make a bigger project.

Sorry for poor explanation and bad english, I hope this helped !

Comment: Thank you so much, 
Can you tell me what to do if I need to check more than one url, i.e. to insert many links into the widget at once?

Comment: You're wlecome, for this you need to first augment the width of the text box for exemple `width=40` and then in the function `SiteCheck` just after `Site_Value=GetSiteBox.get("1.0","end-1c")` you have to add `Site_Value.split("\n")` I tried it and it works perfectly fine. I hope it helped.